# SLD resolution tree, Which predicate applies to give first re-solvent

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, unification

I was thinking I can solve SLD trees till I found this question in past papers.

Which predicate will be picked for the first time?

I assume it is the third rule, but could someone explain to me how to approach this question, by simply showing a procedure of solving `swap([1,2], U)`

How do we unify `([S,H|U])` with `U`?

***EDIT***
Assuming I tried to unify:

`swap([H,S|T], [S,H|U])` with `swap([1,2], U)`

```
[H,S|T] = [1,2], [S,H|U] = U
H = 1, S = 2, T = [], [S,H|U] = U
H = 1, S = 2, T = [], [2,1|U] = U
H = 1, S = 2, T = [], U = [2,1|U]
```

and I end up with `swap([], U'])` but how does this unify with 3 given facts/rules in order to result in `U = [2,1]`

[image: Logic Program Question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When selecting a predicate's clause from the knowledge base you're supposed to rename its variables, consistently, so that they are all "fresh", i.e. new, i.e. no new name in the selected clause was yet seen in the process. For instance,

```
solving:  swap([1,2], U).
selecting: 
          -> swap([], []).   
             <- doesn't match
          -> swap([H0], [H0]).
             <- doesn't match
          -> swap([H1,S1|T1], [S1,H1|U1]) :- swap( T1, U1).
             = matches, with
               { [H1,S1|T1] = [1,2]
               , [S1,H1|U1] = U }
               i.e.
               { H1 = 1, S1 = 2, T1 = [], U = [2,1|U1] }
             -> now solve the body
                swap( T1, U1)
                i.e.
                swap( [], U1) 
                ->
          ........
```

To finish up the example you have to solve `swap( [], U1)` by the same procedure as in this answer, selecting each of the three clauses of the predicate `swap/2`:

1. `swap([], []).` (does it match `swap( [], U1)`?)

   - yes, it does, unifying `U1 = []`.
     this is then used in the unification for `U`, i.e.
     `U = [S1,H1|U1] = [2,1|U1] = [2,1|[]] = [2,1]`.
2. `swap([H2],[H2]).` (does it match `swap( [], U1)`?)
3. etc.

If course you could rename the vars as anything, like `swap([A99],[A99]).`, as long as the renaming is consistent (i.e. rename a variable only once, and use the new name in place of the old one, consistently).

Comment: Thank you, that made much more sense, However, could you explain, to me how prolog obtains U = [2,1]?, What is the second match? Or just simply finish this example?

Comment: the `[S1,H1|U1] = U` is the same as `U = [S1,H1|U1]`. and we also have `{ H1 = 1, S1 = 2 }`. so `2` can be substituted for `S1` and 1 for `H1`. there is no second match, `{ H1 = 1, S1 = 2, T1 = [], U = [2,1|U1] }` is *the same as* `{ [H1,S1|T1] = [1,2], [S1,H1|U1] = U }`. is this what you referred to?

Comment: glad to be of help. next time please type the code from the image, as a text, into your question. otherwise it was a well asked question, and most importantly, you stayed engaged, so kudos to you for that! and happy trails, learning Prolog. :)

Comment: Thank you for that answer aswell, it helped me for my similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

`([S,H|U])` and `U` are not supposed to share the variable U. Before applying a rule, you have to 'freshen' its variables, e.g. by adding an underscore or prime.  You would then unify `([S',H'|U'])` and `U`.

Comment: Could you please show me how you unified this expressions until obtaining first MGU?

Comment: Freshen Its variables?